# HAVING and WHERE SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am studying SQL by myself and searching exercises to practice and I had troubles with one question.

**What was the total population of each continent in 2010?**

We have 2 tables "countries" and "years_population" and this its schema

```
CREATE TABLE countries (
      id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      name TEXT NOT NULL,
      continent TEXT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );
CREATE TABLE population_years (
      id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      population NUMBER,
      year NUMBER,
      country_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(id),
      FOREIGN KEY(country_id) REFERENCES countries(id)
    );
```

To solve it I tried with this code but didn't work:

```
SELECT SUM(population) FROM population_years 
JOIN countries ON countries.id = population_years.country_id 
GROUP BY continent HAVING year = 2010;
```

But the solution is this:

```
SELECT SUM(population), continent FROM population_years
INNER JOIN countries ON
countries.id = population_years.country_id
WHERE year = 2010
GROUP BY continent;
```

My logic was sum the population then join the countries and its population by year(the JOIN clause) then GROUP BY continent and finally choose the year, but What was wrong with my logic?

Comment: You need  having when you want filter an aggregated  result as sum(population). In case the value is not a aggregated  result  you can use where.  the year is a data saved in table row so you can use where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Having` is used to calculate aggregate function. Like in your above case if you want to find out name of the countries having `Sum(population)` is greater then 2,000,000 then you can apply having clause like this

```
   SELECT SUM(population) FROM population_years 
   JOIN countries ON countries.id = population_years.country_id 
   GROUP BY continent HAVING SUM(population) > 2000000;
```

for more info about the same you may find this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

This is your query (with table aliases, qualified column names, and `continent` in the result set):

```
SELECT c.continent, SUM(py.population)
FROM population_years py JOIN
     countries c
     ON c.id = py.country_id 
GROUP BY c.continent
HAVING py.year = 2010;
```

Why doesn't this work?  In fact, in most databases, the query would not even *run*, because you are referring to `year` and it is not in the `GROUP BY` (or defined in the `SELECT`.

What this query is doing is aggregating *all* the rows by continent.  That would be *all* the years.  You are then filtering by year.  SQLite allows this (in violation of the SQL standard).  It just assigns the `year` from an arbitrary row for the comparison.  The calculated values are wrong, though -- assuming there is more than one year.

You want to filter *before* the aggregation.